# How can I install PyInstaller from a local drive?

Tags: installation, pyinstaller, local

I'm using Python 3.6.

I've been looking through StackOverflow and the internet for examples or instruction on how to go about installing PyInstaller from the local drive. I have found a couple things that allude to the process but nothing that defines it clearly.

Our network configuration prevents me from doing the standard 'pip install pyinstaller'. After five consecutive connection timeouts it gives up. Because of this, I have downloaded and unpacked the .gz file and copied from the zip file to a location under my python 3.6 main folder.

Below is the content of that folder.

```
    c:\Python\Python36-32\pyinstaller-2.0>dir
    Volume in drive C is SYSTEM
    Volume Serial Number is DC10-4E85

    Directory of c:\Python\Python36-32\pyinstaller-2.0

    01/07/2020  05:46 AM    <DIR>          .
    01/07/2020  05:46 AM    <DIR>          ..
    01/07/2020  05:45 AM             7,129 .pylintrc
    01/07/2020  05:46 AM    <DIR>          buildtests
    01/07/2020  05:46 AM    <DIR>          doc
    01/07/2020  05:46 AM    <DIR>          e2etests
    01/07/2020  05:46 AM    <DIR>          examples
    01/07/2020  05:45 AM                18 MANIFEST.in
    01/07/2020  05:45 AM    <DIR>          PyInstaller
    01/07/2020  05:45 AM             3,244 pyinstaller-gui.py
    01/07/2020  05:45 AM             2,718 pyinstaller.py
    01/07/2020  05:45 AM             1,741 README.rst
    01/07/2020  05:45 AM             3,778 setup.py
    01/07/2020  05:46 AM    <DIR>          source
    01/07/2020  05:46 AM    <DIR>          support
    01/07/2020  05:46 AM    <DIR>          utils
                   6 File(s)         18,628 bytes
                  10 Dir(s)  370,007,490,560 bytes free
```

Therefore the path to my pyinstaller.py file is:
`C:\Python\Python36-32\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller.py`

I attempted to install it using:
`pip install C:\Python\Python36-32\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller.py`

`(Executed from the pyinstaller-2.0 folder)`

This resulted in:
`Invalid requirement: 'C:\Python\Python36-32\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller.py'
It looks like a path. Does it exist ?`

To which you cannot respond with Y, y, or any variation of yes.

The questions I have are:

> 1. Has anyone successfully done a local install of PyInstaller?
> 2. If this is possible, what is wrong with my syntax above?

Based on the response I am getting from the install of PyInstaller isn't finding the location I am providing even though as you can see, the path is exactly where its 'py' file is located.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly enter this folder:

```
cd C:\Python\Python36-32\pyinstaller-2.0
```

and run this:

```
python setup.py install
```

Only when you download **.whl** file,then you can use `pip install xxxxxx.whl`


Oh,If you do not install other modules that pyinstaller need,maybe it will have some errors.The console will show modules that you do not install.Just install them in the same way.

Comment: @jizhihamSAMA Above didn't work, but returned the following message: setup.py is not yet supposed to work. Please Use PyInstaller without installation.

Comment: @KenCarter So maybe you can use it directly.Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes... I have used varriants of PyInstaller that include the entire path to the py file for it and even not including the py... I've been looking for a whl file to install for python 3.6 but no luck... just the gz that includes the zip with the file structure... Using pip install pyinstaller.py will result in the install trying access the code from the web rather than my hard drive.  That causes the install to be blocked.

Comment: @KenCarter Do you install the modules that pyinstaller need?such as pywin32 and so on.

Comment: Yes.I got a fresh install of 3.6 python and then updated it it with pywin32-227-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl. As far as I'm aware (new python user, we aren't in C# anymore), that is the only addition that I needed before i could proceed to PyInstaller.

Comment: @KenCarter What will happened in the console if you use ```pyinstaller xxxx.py```?

Comment: @KenCarter I find that the version you use is 2.0.Why don't use the newest version?

Comment: @jizhilaoSAMA... you had me for a second... I went back and looked because I was trying to get the latest edition of it. the file PyInstaller-3.5.tar.gz extracts to pyinstaller-2.0.zip.  That Zip contains the pyinstaller-2.0 file structure which I copied to a python sub folder.

Comment: @KenCarter I download PyInstaller-3.5.tar.gz right now.I find the folder structure of pyinstaller is different with your folder structure.emmm......I gonna to sleep,I have final exam tomorrow,I think you can check the version of pyinstaller or use Internet proxy to download pyinstaller ```pip install pyinstaller```.If possible,I will reply to you tomorrow.Good night.

Comment: @jizhilaoSAMA you were correct.  I was assuming that 7-Zip was unpacking the zip file and overwriting it every time. When I open the file with 7-Zip rather than double clicking on it i found a tar file, that I consequently opened to find version 3.5.
I've managed to attempt the install pyinstaller and have gotten further but have found numerous dependencies that I wasn't aware of I've worked through to the installation of 'pefile' and have run into issues with that. It almost looks like I could copy the content of that distro somewhere and be good but documentation says otherwise.

Comment: I was unsuccessful after 3 days of trying to get PyInstaller working on my system. This morning I tried loading up cx_Freeze. it was virtually painless to setup and get working. Thus far, I have only one issue with it, which is that it by default renders the executable with lib folder and Python36.dll that must be included (I'm looking for a single file option). On the plus side building a distribution/installer for the exe is a piece of cake!  Thanks for all the assistance and insight.

Comment: @KenCarter It doesn't matter. I'm glad I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it with getting pyinstaller from its github [page](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller) and install it with

```
python setup.py install
```

in its source.